# EDK SDK confusion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exchange-server, mapi

At work we have a third party library we use called "MAPI LIB". It is version 1.0. I think this came with a very very old version of the Windows Platform SDK. It has libraries like EDKDEBUG.LIB and which I can't find in any platform SDK installed with VS2003, VS2005, or VS2008. This seems like a VC6 thing. For example, one of the symbols in these libraries is IID_IMessage which I can't find in any of my VS2005 platform SDK libs.

Basically our application uses these LIB files to communicate with an Exchange server. The bad thing is that these libs force the inclusion of VC6 related MFC libraries (e.g. MFC4.LIB also from VC6), so I can't really use them.

Why aren't these libs in the more recent versions of the Platform SDK for Windows? Where can I find these libs? Exchange is still here today, so I find it odd that C++ API support for MAPI has been dropped from IDE's after VC6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download MFCMAPI - http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/ - to see how MAPI functions and interfaces need to be linked.